# External monitor zooms out when lid is closed in fedora 27

Tags: fedora, display, multi-monitor, monitors, display-settings

I didn't have this issue in fedora 26, I always closed my lid, now this happens (Screenshots taken in fullscreen)

lid open

[image]

lid closed

[image]

Similar I guess is this [ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kscreen/+bug/1573345), any solution?

**Edit:**

Lid open

```
~ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 720, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.03 +
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94* 
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Lid closed:

```
 ~ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.03 +
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: that screenshot show that one window in fullscreen mode, right? Isn't maybe closing and opening the lid changing the screen resolution? (You'd find out with `xrandr`)

Comment: @TomášPospíšek yes full screen, please read the edit

Comment: Curious. My mother's laptop cycles the resolution of its external display (TV) based on the number of times the lid is closed and opened. Maybe the bugs are related.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams fedora 26 or 27? All was perfectly fine here where I was on 26, so it's an OS bug not a hardware bug in my case

Comment: Probably 27, although I'd have to verify again.

Comment: so now, that we know what's happening, where next? You could make a script that reacts on lid open and sets the screen to the resolution you need with `xrandr`.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek nice idea, will do that tomorrow

Comment: in case any comment was useful you could possibly not forget to mark it as such ...? :-o ;-)

Comment: @TomášPospíšek just did :)